# Setting a variable by an onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to programmatically create links which will, when a link is clicked, set a variable. This variable will be used to load a profile.

Here's the code (with console.logs added in):

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.innerHTML = user.Name;
link.setAttribute("data-role", "button");
link.setAttribute("href", "#page-profile");
var UID = user.UID;
console.log(UID);
link.onclick = function(UID) {
     console.log(UID);
     var profile = UID;
                             }
```

However I'm not quite sure how to pass the variable along to the onclick at runtime.

How do I get a value from a link to a Javascript variable?

This is for a PhoneGap application if that helps.

Edit, as apparently some people feel the question is unclear:

I want to, upon clicking a link, set a variable value based on another variable I have. That's it.

Comment: @Berguiga.M.Amine — Because it won't make this significantly easier.

Comment: You are setting a variable, `var profile`, but it's local to the `onclick` event. Is `UID` the value you want?

Comment: Why don't you just set the relevant data-* attribute, e.g, `data-uid`, then retrieve it inside click handler using `var profile = this.dataset.uid;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set the value of a data attribute for the link, like:

```
link.setAttribute("data-id", user.UID);

link.onclick = function(e) {
 var profile = this.dataset.id;
};
```

Comment: Ya my thought exactly even you could retrieve it using instead: `this.dataset.id`

Comment: I like your idea better, so I edited to match. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> A closure is an inner function that has access to the outer
>   (enclosing) function's variables—scope chain

So do not define UID as a function argument! your function argument is the (click)event in that case!

See my JS Fiddle. (I set static values for the user vars for testing)

https://jsfiddle.net/87jthdpt/1/

Example of the closure

```
var UID = "test";
link.onclick = function(ev) {
    console.log(UID);
    var profile = UID;
}
```